# Using Swift, how do I disable the keyboard from popping up?

Tags: ios, swift, textbox, uipickerview

I am writing an application in Swift 3.0 using xCode.

When I press a textbox, I only want the picker view to show; so, why does the keyboard show with it?
How can I disable it from popping up?

Here is the iPhone without touching the textbox:
[image: picture one]

Here is the iPhone when I touch the textbox:

[image: picture two]

Here is my code for the view controller:

```
//the arrays for the height textbox
var heightInFeet = ["4\' 8\"", "4\' 9\"", "4\' 10\"", "4\' 11\"", "5\'", "5\' 1\"", "5\' 2\"", "5\' 3\"", "5\' 4\"", "5\' 5\"", "5\' 6\"", "5\' 7\"", "5\' 8\"", "5\' 9\"", "5\' 10\"", "5\' 11\"", "6\'", "6\' 1\"", "6\' 2\"", "6\' 3\"", "6\' 4\"", "6\' 5\"", "6\' 6\"", "6\' 7\"", "6\' 8\""]
var heightInMeters = ["1.42", "1.44", "1.46", "1.48", "1.5", "1.52", "1.54", "1.56", "1.58", "1.6", "1.62", "1.64", "1.66", "1.68", "1.7", "1.72", "1.74", "1.76", "1.78", "1.8", "1.82", "1.84", "1.86", "1.88", "2.0", "2.2"]
var pickerArray = [String]()

//the array for the activity level textbox
var activityLevel = ["None/Sedentary", "Light/Low", "Moderate/Active", "High/Very Active"]
```

...

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    var countrows : Int = pickerArray.count

    if pickerView == pickerViewForActivityLevel{
        countrows = self.activityLevel.count
    }
    return countrows
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == pickerViewForHeight{
        let titleRowForHeight = pickerArray[row]
        return titleRowForHeight
    }
    else if pickerView == pickerViewForActivityLevel{
        let titleRowForActivityLevel = activityLevel[row]
        return titleRowForActivityLevel
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == pickerViewForHeight{
        self.heightTextBox.text = self.pickerArray[row]
        self.pickerViewForHeight.isHidden = true
    }
    else if pickerView == pickerViewForActivityLevel{
        self.activityLevelTextBox.text = self.activityLevel[row]
        self.pickerViewForActivityLevel.isHidden = true
    }
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if (textField == self.heightTextBox){
        self.pickerViewForHeight.isHidden = false
    }
    else if (textField == self.activityLevelTextBox){
        self.pickerViewForActivityLevel.isHidden = false
    }
}

@IBAction func heightSwitchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if heightUnitsSwitch.isOn{
        heightUnits.text = "Feet (ft)"
        pickerArray = []
        pickerArray.append(contentsOf: heightInFeet)
    }
    else{
        heightUnits.text = "Meters (m)"
        pickerArray = []
        pickerArray.append(contentsOf: heightInMeters)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turn off the user interaction enabled checkbox.

Comment: Did you set the picker view as the text field's `inputView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set inputView UIView() as an inputView `textField.inputView = UIView()`

Comment: Why would you set the `inputView` to anything other than the picker view?

Comment: because maybe he don't want to set pickerView as an input View because of his UI design. And he just want to hide keyboard because he already have a custom logic in his pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row)

Comment: @VitalyMigunov what a magic!! it works like a charm... after a lot of search for the solution finaly this code solved my problem.. but I still can't understand what happened here? what this code did exactly?  can you explaint it more pls?

Answer (score 1):

If the value in this `inputView` is nil, the text field displays the standard system keyboard when it becomes first responder. Assigning a `custom view` to this `inputView` causes that view to be presented instead.
The default value of this property is nil.so you can use `inputView` for showing picker.

```
 let picker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
 textField.inputView = picker
```